# Android says "Can't play this video" when trying to launch mp4 from local storage

Tags: java, android, video, local, mp4

I've found a couple of related questions but could not find an answer for my specific issue.

I'm trying to launch a video activity which plays a video downloaded to the sdcard. It throws an error saying  "Can't play this video". When I launch the video without the app it plays just fine.

Here I create the activity:

```
VideoView mVideoView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String url = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    setJsonData(url);
    Log.d("URL VID",url);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url); //Declare your url here.
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
    vidControl.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(vidControl);
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.start();
}
```

When I do that I get this error after trying to start the video:

```
06-19 16:57:24.921 26033-26033/com.csform.android.uiapptemplate W/VideoView: Unable to open content: /storage/emulated/0/Nokia%20AirFrame.mp4
java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1120)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1066)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1003)
    at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:437)
    at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:742)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:730)
    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:211)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2420)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1324)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6712)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:894)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:880)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

My permissions are set like this:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the value of `url`?

Comment: The url is /storage/emulated/0/Nokia%20AirFrame.mp4

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Nokia%20AirFrame.mp4` is not a valid `Uri`, and so `Uri.parse()` is likely to give you problems. A `Uri` has a scheme, such as `file` or `content` or `https`.

Answer (score 0):

The `mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);` method needs to be replaced by the `mVideoView.setVideoPath(uri);` method. Here `uri` specifies the path of the video file on the `SDCARD`.

`setVideoURI` is not use when we wanna to load a video from `SDCARD`  and you must use `setVideoPath` . `setVideoURI`  is only for stream video from internet.

Comment: I've tried mVideoView.setVideoPath(url); but I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been a filename issue. I changed the name so it doesn't have spaces or uppercase characters anymore and the error went away and I can play the video.